# How do I know if an embedded Vimeo player is blocked or does not load properly?

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using the API and have browsed their documentation for it but haven't been able to find anything that may be of use; other than possibly applying a timeout function to check to see if the "ready" event ever fires.  I really don't want to use that approach though and it may not even solve the issue of determining whether or not it was blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's the only way at the moment. We'll be making this better in some upcoming updates towards the end of the year.